# Sendmany transaction fees

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

How high are transaction fees for "sendmany"?

Is it correct that using "sendmany" i can send Bitcoins to multiple addresses but only have to pay the transaction fee once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transaction fee is based on the size of the transaction (in bytes), among other factors. Each output adds some length to the transaction, so more destinations will mean a higher fee. With the current transaction fee schedule, roughly every five destinations adds an additional .0005 BTC to the standard fee.

Comment: Note: I was asking about the standard client and I assume David answered for that. I think in theory fees can be chosen arbitrarily if only a miner includes the transaction. Long story short it seems possible to save some fees using sendmany.